# How to sort the posts using their post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using two custom post_types where i display both of them in the search page.
There i need to sort the posts according to their posttype.

```
like if(custom_post_type1)
{
   print all posts under custom_post_type1;
}elseif(custom_post_type2)
{
   print all posts under custom_post_type2;
}
```

I can see that there is query_post , i am not sure about the arguments, specifically i need the post types 1 to be at the first and the other after these posts.
I need to sort in the search result page.

Comment: what do you mean by POST type ? could you refrain your question ?

Comment: He's referring to WordPress post types.

Answer (score 0):

Right from the wordpress [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_parent' => null ); 
$custom_posts = get_posts( $args );
?>
```